# Binding dynamic checkbox in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of options pulled from the database via json based on product selection in angular.js

Here's a sample code:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="extra in extras" ng-model="order.extras" checklist-value="{{ extra.id }}"><strong>{{ extra.name }}</strong></ion-checkbox>
```

I want a user to be able to select multiple extras but can't seem to be able to bind these selections.

Comment: Maybe using `ng-model="extra.model"` ?

Comment: that worked thanks even though I wanted all form field assigned to the order variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could work with `ng-model="order.extras[extra.id]"` then you can track the checked extras in `order.extras`.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/s0qc2L6p/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ionic'])
 .controller('mainController', mainController);
    
function mainController($scope) {
 $scope.order = {};
 $scope.extras = [
     {
        id: 0,
        name: 'first'
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        name: 'second'
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name: 'third'
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.2.4/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<ion-content>
    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="extra in extras" ng-model="order.extras[extra.id]" checklist-value="{{ extra.id }}"><strong>{{ extra.name }}</strong></ion-checkbox>
    
current order: {{order}}
    
</ion-content>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a life saver!